# Error code 3 : No jobs to start for run: [BigQuery transfers]

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm seeing some errors while trying to configure BigQuery transfers for Play reports. It seems like I have configured everything correctly, but I'm getting the following error:

Error code 3 : No jobs to start for run: projects/...

Any ideas?

Thanks!
-patrick

Comment: Please, if you have a support package open there a case providing the job ID. Otherwise, please open a private issue in the Public Issue Tracker with the project number and job id directly [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) and post here the issue number in order to be able to locate you and help you myself.

Comment: Thanks, it magically started to work, and has been since. I guess it might have had something to do with setting up the transfer, which might take some time.

Comment: Then, since this can't be reproduced and there's non clear solution I think it could make sense to delete the question.